# Griffon applications - memory usage

Tags: swing, memory, groovy, jvm, griffon

I have a question referring to Griffon.
Is there a way to decrease memory consumption of griffon applications?
Actually the sample griffon application process (just single window with
label) takes in Windows ~80MB. Is there a way to change something to
visibly decrease this basic memory usage?
Griffon is a great solution etc. but my customer complains that a simple
application takes such an amount of memory (more than e.g. Word,  Outlook,
or most of complicated Java application - comparable with whole).

Comment: _Is there a way to decrease memory consumption of griffon applications?_ unless you explicitly start your application with the `-Xms` argument, probably not. Now, the question would more be why do you use such framework for simple application? Either it is not simple and 80M is nothing (in a 8Gb machine, that's 1% of memory), either the application is simple and you are using a Tomcat to smack a mouse.

Comment: Actually, it is quite relative if we can call my application  simple or not. This is a messenger using two different protocols, database for settings and history, notifications etc. I think using the framework had its motives, and I wouldn't say its using a Tomcat to smack a mouse, but on the other hand - most messengers on Windows consume much less memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A barebones Griffon app (just by calling create-app and nothing more) reports 49M of memory usage. In terms of file size it's a bit above 7M. Whereas a java base Griffon app (`griffon create-app sample --file-type=java`) rises up to 42M of memory usage; same file size.

This is of course using default settings provided by the `run-app` command. Further memory configuration settings may be applied to limit and streamline resource consumption.

Comment: How do You measure this memory consumption? I'm getting this 80MB in Windows Task manager, but I'm sure it's not the most accurate way of measuring memory usage.

Comment: I took those measurements by running `jconsole`, attaching it to the process that runs `griffon.swing.SwingApplication`. Bear in mind that other messengers may take advantage of native support provided by the platform thus leading to lower app memory consumption.